# Verbs that can't be used in the passive

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, passive-voice

Why can't some stative verbs be used in the passive? We can't, for example, passivize *resemble*, but we can passivize *know, love* and *like*?

Comment: Interesting question. _Resemble_ is a reversible verb, in that the subject and object can be reversed without changing meaning; if Bill resembles Mike, then Mike resembles Bill, and we can say they resemble each other. This doesn't leave much room for passive; what would it be used for?  We don't use it much for _marry_, except in the causative: _Bill and Sue were married by John_, but not *_Bill was married by Sue_ or *_Sue was married by Bill_.

Comment: There is a one-to-one correspondence with resemble that does not exist with those verbs where subjects actually do something. Ahem.

Comment: @JohnLawler  Wouldn't you say that "There is a resemblance between John and Harry" makes both parties passive, or is that some other construction?

Comment: There's no passive in that sentence. Lots of syntax, but no passive.

Comment: "John was resembled by Harry"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntactically transitive verbs that don't permit a passive are typically either stative verbs (have (own), lack, deserve, suit, fit, weigh, cost, etc), symmetric verbs (marry, meet) or both (**resemble**, equal).

That *symmetric* verbs can't be made passive is probably because the main point of using a passive is to alter the asymmetry of a construction by promoting the object; when the construction is symmetric this doesn't make any sense.

Meanwhile, the lack of activity in stative verbs makes elevating the object to a subject a bit strange (though not impossible). That some asymmetric stative verbs do allow it, while others don't, is probably mostly chance enforced by usage. Verbs that don't permit passives sometimes function more like copulas than regular transitive verbs, linking the subject with a property rather than linking two participants (eg weigh, cost). Still, I doubt there is a good reason why "I am fitted/suited (by this hat)" is ungrammatical, while "This is known (by me)" is fine.

Comment: 'A good time was had by all' vs *'A good laugh was had by all present'.